# PHP: Display output in a table, I want to echo the Table Heading just once

Tags: php

I am given an activity which asks the calculates the earnings of a user based on the capital and interest per month. I should be able to display the month number, the interest earned that month and the new balance and so on until the term is finished.

So here's my form in HTML:

```
<h1>Please provide the following:</h1>
    <form action="displayInterest.php" method="POST">
     <p>Principal:
         <input name="principal" type="number" maxlength="10"/>
     </p>

    <p>Interest Rate:
        <input name="interest" type="number" maxlength="2"/>
    </p>

    <p>Term:
        <input name="term" type="number" maxlength="2"/>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Complete"/>
 </form>
```

And here is the PHP

```
<?php
$principal = $_REQUEST['principal'];
$interestRate = $_REQUEST['interest'];
$term = $_REQUEST['term'];

print("Your principal amount is $".$principal.", your interest rate is ".$interestRate." % for a term of ".($term)." months.");
print("<br/>");

$earnings;
$monthlyInterest = $interestRate/1200;


for ($month=1; $month<$term+1; $month++)
{
    $earnings = number_format($principal*$monthlyInterest,2);
    $principal+=$earnings;
    echo("<table id=test>
                <tr>
                    <th>month</th>
                    <th>Interest</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>$month</td>
                    <td>$$earnings</td>
                    <td>$$principal</td>
                </tr>
           </table>
            ");

}

?>
```

So I would get something like this, (assuming he invests $10000 for 5 months at 5% annual interest.
The table heading would be printed out in all iterations, since it's a loop. How do I get around with this. If I echo the table heading outside the loop, it would separate the two tables and formatting will not be as one table. So I just want to have one heading.

```
Your principal amount is $10000, your interest rate is 5 % for a term of 5 months.
Month   Interest    Balance
1       $41.67      $10041.67
Month   Interest    Balance
2       $41.84      $10083.51
Month   Interest    Balance
3       $42.01      $10125.52
Month   Interest    Balance
4       $42.19      $10167.71
Month   Interest    Balance
5       $42.37      $10210.08
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `table`, first `tr` and closing `table` **outside** `for` loop:

```
echo("<table id=test>
                <tr>
                    <th>month</th>
                    <th>Interest</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                </tr>");

for ($month=1; $month<$term+1; $month++)
{
    $earnings = number_format($principal*$monthlyInterest,2);
    $principal+=$earnings;
    echo("<tr>
                    <td>$month</td>
                    <td>$$earnings</td>
                    <td>$$principal</td>
                </tr>");
}
echo ("</table>");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking of doing that. But I put in the closing tags. I didn't know you can break up html in PHP. I'm new to PHP, so this helps a lot.

Comment: It did, it's gonna help me a lot more in the future.